# Is it possible to Clip in ArcGIS Explorer?

Tags: clip, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-explorer

Is it possible to clip in ArcGIS Desktop Explorer?

Or does anyone know of any Analysis Servers I can connect to to get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no clip analysis tool available within the default application, however you can create your own clip geoprocessing service and use that within ArcGIS Explorer.  See the following links below:

[Using geoprocessing services in ArcGIS Explorer for Windows Desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_geoprocessing_services_in_ArcGIS_Explorer_for_Windows_Desktop/005700000053000000/)

[Geoprocessing service example: Clip And Ship](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005700000073000000)